# Что значат скобки в выражении var userClone = cop({ from, to}, user);?

Tags: javascript

Что значит { from, to} в выражении?

`var userClone = cop({ from, to}, user);`

Как это прочитать(заранее извиняюсь за тупой вопрос)?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment#destrukturizatsiya-obekta

Comment: это не деструктуризация

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае вызывается функция `cop()` и в нее передаются два параметра, один из которых является объектом и еще второй параметр - user.

Первый параметр это литерал объекта, и обычно он создается следующим образом:

```
const range = {
    from: 1,
    to: 5
}
```

но, если требуется создать объект из существующих переменных, то можно при создании объекта их туда передать вместо значений:

```
const from= 1;
const to= 5;
const range = {
    from: from,
    to: to
}
```

но в таком случае названия полей объекта и переменных from и to совпадают, соответсвенно можно написать в сокращенном варианте:

```
const from= 1;
const to= 5;
const range = {
    from,
    to
}
```

и вот пример если бы названия переменных не совпадали:

```
const min = 1;
const max = 5;
const range = {
    from: min,
    to: max
}
```